# What is the general steps to simplify an equation representing a rotated curve

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

If I draw the curve represented by equation $$x^2+2xy-y^2=1$$, I see a rotated hyperbola. How to transform this equation in oder to obtain the standard form $$X^2-Y^2=1$$?

Using the hint provided by the first answer, I got eigenvalues $$\pm\sqrt{2}$$ and eigenvectors:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}} \end{bmatrix}$$

How to determine how much rotation needs to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Diagonalize the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&-1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I got eigenvalues $sqrt(2)$ and $-sqrt(2)$ and their eigenvectors. How to know how much rotation needs to occur?

Comment: The eigenvectors (which should be orthogonal) give you the axes.